# Spark SQL ignores parquet.compression propertie specified in TBLPROPERTIES

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql, parquet

I need to create a Hive table from Spark SQL which will be in the PARQUET format and SNAPPY compression.
The following code creates table in PARQUET format, but with GZIP compression:

```java
hiveContext.sql("create table NEW_TABLE stored as parquet tblproperties ('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY') as select * from OLD_TABLE")
```

But in the Hue "Metastore Tables" -> TABLE -> "Properties" it still shows:

```
|  Parameter            |  Value   |
| ================================ |
|  parquet.compression  |  SNAPPY  |
```

If I change SNAPPY to any other string e.g. **ABCDE** the code still works fine with exception that compression is still GZIP:

```java
hiveContext.sql("create table NEW_TABLE stored as parquet tblproperties ('parquet.compression'='ABCDE') as select * from OLD_TABLE")
```

And Hue "Metastore Tables" -> TABLE -> "Properties" shows:

```
|  Parameter            |  Value   |
| ================================ |
|  parquet.compression  |  ABCDE   |
```

This make me think that TBLPROPERTIES are just ignored by Spark SQL.

**Note:** I tried to run the same query directly from Hive and in case when the property was equals to SNAPPY table was created successfully with proper compression (i.e. SNAPPY not GZIP).

```sql
create table NEW_TABLE stored as parquet tblproperties ('parquet.compression'='ABCDE') as select * from OLD_TABLE
```

In case when the property was **ABCDE** the query didn't failed, but table wasn't been created.

Question is what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion)

> When reading from and writing to Hive metastore Parquet tables, Spark
>   SQL will try to use its **own** Parquet support **instead of Hive SerDe** for
>   better performance.

Then just below, you will find some properties that control whether Spark enforces all Hive options (and performance...) i.e. `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet`, and how to handle raw read/write on Parquet files such as `spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec` *(gzip by default - you should not be surprised)* or `spark.sql.parquet.int96AsTimestamp`.

Anyway, the "default compression" properties are just indicative. Within the same table and directory, each Parquet file may have its own compression settings -- and page size, HDFS block size, etc.

Comment: Ah, and Spark clearly does not check the values of "TblProperties" pushed to the Metastore -- but the Metastore *does* check. Looks like there's an exception that is not trapped properly, so the Metastore does not create the table definition... but Spark creates the files on the expected directory anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This is the combo that worked for me (Spark 2.1.0):

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=GZIP")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE test_table USING PARQUET PARTITIONED BY (date) AS SELECT * FROM test_temp_table")
```

Verified in HDFS:

```
/user/hive/warehouse/test_table/date=2017-05-14/part-00000-uid.gz.parquet
```

Comment: For the record, the compression codecs supported for Parquet are `none`, `snappy`, `gzip`, and `lzo`-- while for ORC you must type `zlib` instead of `gzip` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html